# Delphi Insert SubMenu item to MainMenu of another application with click event

Tags: delphi

I wondering how i can insert new item to mainmenu of another application with click event

```
procedure TMainForm.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
HwndWind:HWND;
hMainMenu:Integer;
MenuInfo: TMENUITEMINFO;
begin
  HwndWind :=  FindWindow(nil,PChar('Test App'));
  if HwndWind <> 0 then
  Begin
    hMainMenu := GetMenu(HwndWind);

    hMainMenu := GetSubMenu(hMainMenu, 0);

    MenuInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(MenuInfo);

    MenuInfo.fMask := MIIM_ID or MIIM_SUBMENU or MIIM_TYPE;
    MenuInfo.fType := MFT_STRING;
    MenuInfo.fState := 0;
    MenuInfo.dwTypeData := '&File';

    InsertMenuItem(hMainMenu,1,True,MenuInfo);
  End;

end;
```

i know i miss a lot but please if anyone can point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Comment: Step 1 is to add the error checking that you missed, and then report back to us with the outcome. You must read the documentation for these functions and heed it. Don't ignore checking for errors. Only Chuck Norris can call Win32 API functions without checking for errors.

Comment: And the other mistake you make is that you fail to initialise the entire record. You should ensure that all fields have a well defined value before passing the record to the API function.

Comment: As David points towards the end of his answer, adding a menu item to another application is only part of the problem. It's pointless adding the item without being able to control what happens when the new item is clicked. So you may want to think about how to write the other application in such a way that it can support a plugin framework making it easier for the first application to add items with appropriate callbacks.

Comment: @CraigYoung: You are assuming that the OP has control over the other app and can make changes to it.  There are plenty of examples of third-party add-on programs manipulating other people's menus.

Comment: I reverted the edit. The edit asks a different question. Please ask it as a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental mistake that you are making is that you are failing to check for errors. This means that you have simply no idea where your code is wrong. As I explained to you in some detail in your previous question, checking for errors is critically important. It is disappointing to find myself repeating the message.

This is what your code should look like:

```
hMainMenu := GetMenu(HwndWind);
Win32Check(hMainMenu<>0);

hMainMenu := GetSubMenu(hMainMenu, 0);
Win32Check(hMainMenu<>0);

MenuInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(MenuInfo);

MenuInfo.fMask := MIIM_ID or MIIM_SUBMENU or MIIM_TYPE;
MenuInfo.fType := MFT_STRING;
MenuInfo.fState := 0;
MenuInfo.dwTypeData := '&File';

Win32Check(InsertMenuItem(hMainMenu, 1, True, MenuInfo));
```

When you run this you will find that the call to `InsertMenuItem` fails with error code 87, `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. Which parameter is invalid? The `MENUITEMINFO` struct is not initialised correctly. You only initialise some of the fields, and the rest contain stack noise. Make sure that you initialise the entire struct. For instance:

```
....
ZeroMemory(@MenuInfo, SizeOf(MenuInfo));
MenuInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(MenuInfo);
....
```

For the sake of completeness I must remind you that error checking mechanisms vary from function to function in the Win32 API. There is no uniformity to the error checking design. Always read the documentation for every single function that you use to find out how to check for errors correctly.

Finding a way to respond when the menu item is clicked will be more difficult. You are going to need to respond to the `WM_COMMAND` messages sent to the window. That can only be done from the window procedure. And that code executes in the context of the thread that created the window. Which is a thread in the other process. All of which means that you need to inject code into this other process. At which point you may as well do all the work in the injected code. There's little point extending the menus in an external module, but then responding to them in a different injected module.

Once you realise that injection is not a very pleasant solution to any problem you may contemplate trying to solve the underlying problem in a different way. Is it possible for this other application to be extended in a less invasive manner than your external process injecting into it?

Comment: A `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` could receive the `WM_COMMAND` message. Put the hook procedure into a DLL, and then use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to get the target window's thread ID and pass that to `SetWindowsHookEx()`. The DLL can then get the click event and send that info back to the main app via an IPC mechanism for processing.

Comment: @Remy That's injection isn't it?

Comment: Since it is hooking another process, yes it is injected, but automatically by the OS, the hooking app's code does not have to perform the actual injection, like with `CreateRemoteThread()` or other common injection techniques. You were implying that injection has to be difficult and complex, but in this case it does not have to be. And you don't have to inject in order to add the menu, `InsertMenuItem()` works across process boundaries. So injecting the menu insertion code into the other process, like you suggested, is overkill.

Comment: I wonder if 'mass invite' is something that can be executed outside the context of the target app, in a message hook. I also wonder why does the system perform automatic marshalling for the item string...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I'm not sure what you mean by 'mass invite'. I also wonder why the system marshals the string. I wonder if it dates back to 16 bit days. Cross-process UI was much more common then.

Comment: @David - It's just the appended item's text as per original poster's own answer. Related with some 'paltalk' according to comments in the source..

Comment: @RemyLebeau i have successfully inject the dll and add the new item but  the problem is in the click event how i can call it ? (the question was update above) thanks for the injection direction.

Comment: @Abdulrahman: as stated earlier, you have to intercept the `WM_COMMAND` message that is sent to the window that is registered to receive the menu's messages. You can use `SetWindowsHookEx()` for that.

Comment: Remy is quite right that `SetWindowsHookEx` is a much cleaner way to do the injection